# Beagle Bone Green rootfs in RAM

Tags: embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

) I use Beagle Bone Green for my project. I am building my custom image with buildroot. I want a solution to be able to load the kernel image and rootfs with my apps from u-boot via tftp, but on the other hand I want to be able to use eMMC for some permanent files... What options do I have? Thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **initrd/initramfs** for your rootfs and mount the emmc into that, e.g. /var or /mnt
- **nfsroot** your rootfs is  on a network drive, you can still mount the eMMC into any directory you want for device specific storage
- **partition eMMC** download your rootfs image and write it to one partition on boot (usually from within initramfs). Keep your permanent data in a second eMMC partition. This approach can be useful if either of the previous don't work out e.g. due to not enough RAM or network limitations.

There are probably some other variations that I didn't mention, but those should be the most common.